# hide link multiple times - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two links. One is displayed and the other one is hidden. After I click the first link, it should disappear and the second one should display. After I click the second one like before the first one should appear in her place.

This is my code:

HTML

```
<a class="link-one" href="javascript:void(0)" rel="do-2">Link one</a>
<a class="link-two" href="javascript:void(0)" rel="do-3">Link two</a>
```

jQuery

```
$(".link-one").live('click',function(){
    //some actions
    $(this).hide();
    $(".link-two").show().on('click',function(){
        //some actions
        $(this).hide();
        $("link-one").show();
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.link-two{ display: none;}
```

Could someone please give me a hint on what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: If your version of jQuery supports the .on() method, I would use it exclusively over the .live() method.  Also, can you please describe your problem more?  What happens?

Comment: The issue is that when I click on the second link both links show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better solution, give both links a common class, then just use one function (lets use the class `alterLink`)

```
$(".alterLink").click(function() {
    /*
    $(this).hide();
    $(".alterLink").not(this).show();
    */

    //Per comments, this is easier (assuming only 2 links)
    $(".alterLink").toggle();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zDQde/

Comment: Or, just `$('.alterLink').toggle();` to flip both.

Comment: @Blazemonger -- Ahh, yup, overlooked it. Edited to include that, much easier.

Comment: @Blazemonger If there's only 2 links you're spot on.

Comment: @PatsyIssa Which there are.

Answer (score 1):

For starters live is deprecated, use .on instead, your first selector is missing the .

So without further ado:

```
$(".link-one, .link-two").on('click',function(){
    $(".link-one, .link-two").toggleClass('hidden');
});

.hidden
{
display:none;
}
```

And start off with the class hidden on your link-two.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.link-one,.link-two').click(function () {
    $('.link-one,.link-two').toggle()
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rzmxF/)**